# Composition over Inheritance for Javascript Example

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, composition

For a certain function Building, we have certain children (Tower, Mansion, Hut, etc.) that inherit the methods from Building.

These methods can be things like:

```js
setName()
setColor(color)
setSize(x,y)
(...)
```

The problem is when I start having too many methods in this base Building object. However, I know that all Huts, Mansions, etc. MUST have these methods.

With naive inheritance, each Hut, Mansion, etc. object will have very few methods, and the only methods that are included are the ones that need to "override" the base Building methods.

So, if I were to favor composition over inheritance and try to get each Building type to have its own composition of parts, how can I make that as clean as possible?

Will I have to go through each Building type and write each prototypal method that used to be in Building object?

Also, what would, say, the Mansion object compose of? Instead of inheriting Building, will it just include a Building object as one of its parts?

Comment: No, parts would be like roof, door, window, etc.

Comment: you could group associated methods into Objects and compose the prototypes of the subClasses `Object.assign(Hut.prototype, doorsMixin); Object.assign(Mansion.prototype, doorsMixin, windowsMixin, poolMixin);`

Comment: @kevin-hu We need more detail, preferably a look at your code. You say you're inheriting too many methods while at the same time saying your subtypes *must* inherit all those methods.

Comment: @Thomas That's not object composition. That Object.assign pattern still solves -- and suffers from -- all the same problems as inheritance.